# Openbox disable Alt+F4

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.10, openbox

Every time I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, the window I have opened in Openbox (3.6.1) gets closed.

I tried to follow the official instructions but it didn't work:

1. I removed the following from `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`:

   ```xml
   <keybind key="A-F4">
      <action name="Close"/>
   </keybind>
   ```
2. Executed:

   ```
   openbox --reconfigure
   ```
3. And finally restarted.

However, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> still keeps closing the current window.

Comment: Lease the lines there, but set to action name="" to disable Alt+F4.

Comment: Maybe this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139907/openbox-disable-alt-f4-on-per-application-basis will help you.

Comment: I Tried leaving it empty, didn't work, I'm going to try the if thing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With credit to [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139907/openbox-disable-alt-f4-on-per-application-basis), you can disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> combination in Openbox by editing `.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` with code similar to:

```
<keybind key="A-F4">
  <action name="If">
    <title>* Chromium</title>
    <then>
      <!-- Do nothing when Chrome is the active window -->
    </then>
    <else>
      <!-- Do nothing in other cases as well -->
    </else>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to include a `#` in the command to disable it
(if you ever want to re-activate it some other time):

```
action name="#Close"/
```

Then run:

```
openbox --reconfigure
```